# Why is Windows running low on memory and crashing all my applications?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, java, crash

I have to be quick in writing this because my web browsers keep crashing on me with memory error codes! I can't even install Java because the installer throws some kind of memory error as well. I took screen snippets of all the error messages I could.

[Task Manager Weird Memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9v1H.png)

[Chrome Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRPRh.png)

[Java Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuxnZ.png)

[Chrome Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D6m4.png)

If anyone could please help me understand why I'm getting these errors, I would much appreciate it. I have an HP Pavillion with an AMD Ryzen 5 4600H processor and 8 GB of DDR4 RAM and a Nvidea Geforce gtx 1050 gpu.

Thanks!

Comment: Close more Chrome tabs.  Also "windows audio device graph isolation" does not look like it is doing the right thing.  Install malwarebytes and run a scan.  If no malware, look into [disabling sound enhancements](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+sound+enhancements&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS868US868&oq=disable+sound++enhancements) for the sound card and see if that doesn't give you back a chunk of ram.  From what I see.. you don't need more swap space.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize memory usage, I would recommend disabling junk processes that start with Windows. All those process eat your RAM and therefore you can get to the end of it.

One tool that does that is [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). You can really mess up your computer with it so be careful.

Another tool which is useful for memory optimization is [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). It's like Task Manager but much more advanced. Process Explorer will allow you to see memory allocation for each process.

Good luck!

Comment: Good advice.. but before pulling in the BIG GUNS of Autoruns, you might start with the simple controls for startup items that were added to the windows 10 task manager.

Answer (score -1):

Please check HDD free space, in case is nearly full it will crash.
Another option set 8Gb swap file, windows call it exchange space.
Its in system properties.
Detals you find on microsoft page:)
Vale
Piotr

Comment: I have a 256 GB SSD with 24 GB left. is that okay?

Comment: This case almost never happens.  Yes, you have enough free to show that this problem has nothing to do with a swap file.